# What is the most efficient way to detect if the date has changed?

Tags: java, android, date, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I want to do a running trainer app. For some of the things that I do I need to know when a day has passed, meaning the date has changed(at 24:00).

Here are some options:

- Of course I can always check if the current time is smaller then 24:00, which is not efficient.
- Also I saw that I can use intent filter - `ACTION_DATE_CHANGED` - and along with a broadcast receiver which will listen to this intent i will know when the date has changed.
  However I think that this is not the most efficient way because its always listen and probably will take some battery and CPU. Android probably did a good job in making broadcast receivers efficient, however I am still wonder whether it's appropriate for my needs.
- Use an alarm manager?

Which is best, or is there a different way? What do you suggest and why?

Comment: Do you need to know WHEN a date changes or do you need to know when running your app if the date is different than the last time the app was used?

Comment: *I am new to this forum* FYI, Stack Overflow is not a forum. It is a Q&A site, so it works differently. To get the most out of SO, I would suggest taking the [Quick Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/about) first, see also [Ask].

Comment: Intent filters don't work by polling. They register themselves with the system, which simply notifies them of the action they are registered for. So you won't be wasting CPU cycles and battery by doing so (unless the action you registered for consumes battery itself - such as looking up the current location).

Comment: How can i add more details which will help? the question speak for iteslf - what is the most efficient way to detect if the date has changed, i guess there is probabley 1-2 ways to do it in a most efficient way.

Comment: Anyway, i need to know when the date has change at all times, but it would be nice to know also how to do it if the app is only running(in background or foreground). what more details do you need?

Answer (score 3):

If you need to take an action each time it is 00:00 you have to use an AlarmManager and a BroadcastReceiver. Then you'll be able to do whatever you have to do inside the onReceive() method of the receiver. Oh and by the way, BroadcastReceivers are the most efficient way to do this, as they keep the device active only during the onReceive() method.

Use the AlarmManager to set a repeating call to onReceive each day at 00:00. If you need an example tell me in the comments.

Other than that, if you don't have to take any action once a day has passed, you can simply check inside the app itself. You can always save the last time your app was opened into SharedPreferences.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, can you give some code for how to do this, and how to connect between the AlarmManager  and the BroadcastReceiver? Also is there a chance that when the app is running in foreground or in background the AlarmManager  will miss the time change, meaning will not notify when 00:00 has passed/reached?